# Vertical Scroll Bars in Sticky Footer

Tags: css, footer, scrollbars, sticky

I am a newbie with css coding (which very much shows) - can anybody help me get the two scroll bars off my [page site is here](http://www.signature-online.net/chamberofcommerce).

The css is in a file called http://www.signature-online.net/chamberofcommercemainstyle2.css and if anybody can help me from ripping my hair out again I would be most grateful!

The footer isn't sticking, and there are two vertical scrollbars, what have I done?

Comment: give overflow:hidden to #main rather overflow:auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what do you need to do is to `#main` set `overflow: hidden` and `padding-bottom: 372px` and you're set to go!

**EDIT[1]:** Sorry you don't need to set `#wrapper` `margin-bottom: 186px`, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `main` class in you `css` like the following:

```
#main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You had `overflow: auto;` and we don't want that, also remove `padding-bottom: 186px;` and  change your `footer` class, just remove `margin-top: -186px;` add `bottom: 0` and it should look like this:

```
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 186px;
    clear: both;
    background-image: url(common/images/footer_mountains.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;
    z-index: 600;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @skmasq and Luis Sánchez 

both of you are amazing! Fantastic! It worked brilliantly! And so quickly too, thank you so much!

Comment: @BillTeale Remember to mark it as answered if it was of help to you (it's the check below the points of the answer) and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: I have one more question related to the same page, I hope this is ok to pick your brains. I am so nervous of messing things up, but I would like to add a white background color to behind the nivo slider that would fill the rest of the page. Is that possible at all? Once again, thanks for any help, and kudos to those who know what they are doing with this css!